# Calling stored procedures with an OUT parameter in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

To call a Stored procedure with an IN parameter is easy like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `catalog_delete_product`(IN `inProductId` INT) BEGIN DELETE FROM product_attribute WHERE product_id = inProductId; DELETE FROM product_category WHERE product_id = inProductId; DELETE FROM shopping_cart WHERE product_id = inProductId; DELETE FROM product WHERE product_id = inProductId; END
```

You can see that it is as easy as that. But how do we call an OUT parameter in MySQL Stored parameter and use it in PHP?

Comment: @Nigel Ren Well I searched and searched but couldn't find an answer here or anywhere until I by chance came across mysqltutorial. But if the community thinks its duplicate, then I can delete it

Comment: It's up to you if you want to delete it as some may find it useful.

Comment: Instead of using OUT parameters, simply select the variable at the end of the procedure and you can use the result set in PHP as you would any other result set. This saves you executing another query. OUT parameters are useful when you call a procedure from another procedure, not when passing information back to application.

Comment: @slaakso that is what I did before. It worked on localhost but not on live server

Comment: There is no difference between local or remote (live) server. If you can make a connection to the server(s), they should work alike with PHP. If you have a problem with one server, you can make a question out of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example to illustrate it, I will a real world practical example(inserting data into an order table and returning the lastInsertId).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `shopping_cart_create_order`(IN `inCartId` INT(11), OUT `newOrderId` INT(11)) BEGIN
    DECLARE newOrder int;
    -- Insert a new record into orders and obtain the new order ID
    INSERT INTO orders (created_on) VALUES (NOW());

    -- Obtain the new Order ID
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO newOrder;

    SET newOrder = newOrderId;
END
```

At PHP level// Probably at the Model/Entity level First, we need to execute the

> shopping_cart_create_order()

stored procedure. Which might probably be in a function.

Second, to get the last order id, we need to query it from the variable

> @oid

. It is important that we must call the method

> closeCursor()

of the PDOStatement object in order to execute the next SQL statement.

```
function query($pdo, $sql, $parameters = []){
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($parameters);
    return $query;
}

function create_order($pdo, $cart_id){
    // Binding the parameters
    $parameters = [':cart_id' => $cart_id];

    // calling stored procedure command
    $sql = 'CALL shopping_cart_create_order(:cart_id)';

    // prepare for execution of the stored procedure, pass value to the command 
    and execute the Stored Procedure
    $query = query($pdo, $sql, $parameters);

   // Then close Cursor. It is important for you to close it.
    $query->closeCursor();

   // execute the second query to get last insert id
    $row = $pdo->query("SELECT @oid AS oid")->fetch();
    return $row;    
}
```